# Can redirecting stdout and stderr to the same file mangle lines?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I've read that when redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file using `2>&1`, `stdout` is usually block buffered while `stderr` is unbuffered.

If a very long line is written to `stdout`, requiring two separate flushes of the buffer, could it happen that a line from `stderr` slips in the middle? Something like this:

```
stdout:   aaaaaaaa.....really long line......aaaaaaaaaaaa<newline>

stderr:   eee<newline>

combined: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeee<newline>
          aaaaaaa<newline>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, exactly that can happen if lines to `stdout` are long enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for (1..10) {
    print "START"; print "-" x 100000; print "END\n";
    warn "!\n";
}
```

Running:

```
./writer.pl > out 2>&1
```

Checking: Open file `out` in an editor and find stderr `!` in between `-`, not always between `END` and `START`

This will vary between OS:s, languages and systems in various ways, but your basic assumption is correct. Experiment by varying length of stdout-lines: `print "-" x 100`, `print "-" x 10000` etc.